Solution to Stochastic Differential Equation Including Heaviside Step Function
There has been several entries on solving deterministic differential equations that include indicator functions. Stochastic differential equations may introduce new difficulties. Namely, does the usual technique used in the deterministic situation, of dividing the domain into intervals, still apply?
Take the following SDE: $$\mathrm{d}X_t= (\mu\mathrm{d}t+\sigma \mathrm{d}W_t)\theta(X_t)$$
Here, $\theta$ is the unit step function, $W_t$ the Weiner process, and $\mu$ and $\sigma$ Real-valued constants.
Can a general solution be produced?

What  did you try yourself?

Putting an integral sign on both sides and thinking maybe that was problematic already

The following works to me.
proc = StratonovichProcess[\[DifferentialD]x[t] == 
 UnitStep[x[t]] *\[DifferentialD]t + 
UnitStep[x[t]] \[DifferentialD]w[t], x[t], {x, 1}, t, 
  w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]];
RandomFunction[proc, {0., 5., 0.01}]
ListLinePlot[%]


I use UnitStep instead of HeavisideTheta since the latter is an attempt to implement a generalized function, not a usual function, in Mathematica.

The result with proc = StratonovichProcess[\[DifferentialD]x[t] ==     HeavisideTheta[x[t]] *\[DifferentialD]t +      HeavisideTheta[x[t]] \[DifferentialD]w[t], x[t], {x, 1}, t,    w \[Distributed] WienerProcess[]] is the same up to randomness.
